# Winapi - passing LPWCSTR as LPCSTR

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I use CreateWindowEx which expands to CreateWindowExA. That function uses LPCSTR types. I would like to pass as a second argument MSFTEDIT_CLASS (from Richedit.h):

```
#define MSFTEDIT_CLASS L"RICHEDIT50W"
```

The following casting doesn't work:

```
(LPCSTR)MSFTEDIT_CLASS
```

CreateWindowEx returns NULL. It works when I pass the second argument this way:

```
"RICHEDIT50W"
```

but I don't want to copy a string from the header. How to fix that ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CreateWindowExW?

Comment: `CreateWindowEx` will expand to `CreateWindowExA` *or* `CreateWindowExW` depending on the existence of the `UNICODE` macro.

Comment: It is pretty questionable that this control can operate correctly in ANSI mode.  Afaik there is no RICHEDIT50A class, like there is for previous versions of the control.  They did a lot of work to support Unicode better in this version, in spite of RTF's legacy.  The only sensible advice is to use RICHEDIT_CLASSA (version 2.0)

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. So do you think that `CreateWindowExA` might not be able to create the `RICHEDIT50W`?

Comment: It will create the window just fine, I can't promise anything about processing the text it contains.  Never seen anybody try to pull that off.  In general the only real reason to use v5.0 instead of v2.0 is for its improved Unicode support.  The feature he can't rely on.

Comment: *The following casting doesn't work:* -- If you removed the cast and recompiled the code, the compiler will tell you that the code will not work properly.  By casting, you told the compiler to "keep quiet, I know what I'm doing", but you see the consequences of doing that.

Comment: @bar: The character set used in communicating with a window is established at window class *registration* time, not at window creation time. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw) has more information. You can certainly create a `"RICHEDIT50W"` window calling `CreateWindowExA`, and it will be a Unicode window. Calling `GetMessageA` (and friends) isn't going to end well, though. And you *are* calling `GetMessageA`, if you rely on the generic-text mappings, as the author of this question is.

Comment: There's no reason at all in 2020 to be building multibyte apps. Switch to Unicode.

Comment: Heck, there's not much reason in 2000 to be building multibyte apps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only a single, viable solution here: Call `CreateWindowExW`, either directly or by defining the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol and have the generic-text mapping `CreateWindowEx` expand to `CreateWindowExW`.

The window you are creating is a Unicode window, always. The character set used for communicating with a window is set at class registration time. The window class named `"RICHEDIT50W"` is registered using [RegisterClassExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassexw) by the system. You don't have control over this.

Since you are eventually going to have to talk to the window using messages, you will need to use the Unicode variants of the message handling functions (`GetMessageW`, `DispatchMessageW`, etc.). You cannot use the ANSI versions, unless you are happy with an application, that sometimes doesn't fail.