# winapi - how to use RICHEDIT_CLASSA (version 2.0)?

Tags: winapi

I have created a window application using Visual Studio 2017 template. CreateWindowEx expands to CreateWindowExW. I create an edit window this way:

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));

hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(
   0, 
   MSFTEDIT_CLASS, 
   TEXT("Type here"),
   WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
   100, 
   100, 
   100,
   30,
   gHwnd, 
   NULL, 
   hInst, 
   NULL);
```

MSFTEDIT_CLASS is defined as L"RICHEDIT50W" in Richedit.h [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666838/winapi-passing-lpwcstr-as-lpcstr) topic contains advice that I should use RICHEDIT_CLASSA (version 2.0). How to achieve it ?

Comment: You are mis-reading the advice. It says that if you **must** use a rich edit control in an application that cannot be built as a Unicode application, you *could* try to instantiate a window class, that's probably not even supported anymore. You are starting out fresh. You have no reason to not write a Unicode application.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are four versions for rich edit control:

- Rich Edit Version 1.0
- Rich Edit Version 2.0
- Rich Edit Version 3.0
- Rich Edit Version 4.1

The original specification for rich edit controls is Microsoft Rich Edit 1.0; the current specification is Microsoft Rich Edit 4.1.

It is suggested to use latest version for new application.

More detailed information about features supported on different versions you can refer to  [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-rich-edit-controls).